# Where to get PCL boost libraries with -mgw48 postfix?

Tags: boost, cmake-gui

I'm working with MinGW not Visual Studio to compile openCV libraries to use them in a Qt .pro project.
My problem is my library files in boost folder are all `-vc100` while CMake is trying to find `-mgw48` files.

My libraries are in this directory:

> C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib

and their name are like : `boost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_49.lib`
but I want them to be like : `boost_date_time-mgw48-mt-1_49.lib`
so that CMake could recognize them.

Where can I download PCL with `-mgw48` libraries?

Comment: You will typically build them yourself using bjam with the toolset option set to mingw. I'm on my phone right now but this should point you towards the relevant documentation

Comment: I installed PCL all in once and the boost libraries were generated automatically in the path:
C:\Program Files\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\li

After that I downloaded boost library itself and ran the bjam file and it hadn't any option to choose. also in the end I couldn't find such libraries.